# bootstrap not working, file not found

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `bootstrap framework` in my website that I'm designing for a university assignment, and despite my best efforts bootstrap doesn't want to play nicely.

With the page open in Chrome, I can open the console and it's complaining it can't find the bootstrap file (see [img]). I have the html file in a folder called httpdocs, and folders called assets with a js, css, and img folder within the assets folder. The links are as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css>" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm not exactly new to html/css/jquery and to my knowledge that path should link correctly, but for some reason it isn't. Any ideas?

[[image: File not found error in Chrome console]]

```
<!-- start section body -->
    <div class="container>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just to cover all bases, is this how I should be marking it up? I have a sidebar on the left hand side of the page that spans `220px` from the very left of the page, and I want the text in the paragraph to not be hidden by that sidebar. Taking that into consideration, how would I then also offset the div for the paragraph to be centered between the edge of the sidebar and the edge of the screen?

I see tutorials using the following instead. Is this an older version of bootstrap or am I trying to use the wrong thing?

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the code where you load/require the bootstrap files

Comment: The class like span9 is for older version of bootstrap and the class like `col-*` are for newer version of bootstrap. What version are you trying with?

Comment: The snippet which uses col-lg-9 col-lg-offset3 is up to date afaik. I use these classes usually when employing the bootstrap column format. It should produce the desired effect for you.

Comment: I've updated the OP to include the code to link the files. I'm using the latest stable version I think; v3.3.6 Note: I did try with the col-lg-9 col-lg-offset9 and it gave the same result.

Comment: Does it work if you use the url references to the source? You can find them here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: To start with, your stylesheet's `href` value contains a trailing `>`.

Comment: @chrisv yes that's worked! Still don't understand why linking to an offline file hasn't worked...

Comment: Good! Please provide some info about your folder structure then... A lot easier to help you out with that info. And also as previously mentioned, remove the ending bracket > in bootstrap.css

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks, that worked! The offline files are now linking correctly :) Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see an extra `>` in the `href` attribute's value.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css>" />
```

Not sure if this is a typo or this is how your actual code is.

You could also provide the links of the other two assets which were not found to confirm the issue.

Comment: Should be a comment rather.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly because the relative path is wrong. We could debug it if you tell us the project structure.
Temporarily you could use bootstrap CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, using bootstrap CDN does solve the issue, **but the other solution is removing the trailing > in the file path.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css>" />
```

corrected to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The file path urls in the `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` errors inside your snapshots clearly indicate that you are directly accessing the web page in chrome and not through a `web-server`.

First I'd like to point out, that even though Chrome is able to open up a "`local`" file, there is a lot of things that tend to go haywire.

Next is, Frameworks like `bootstrap` are more than a normal `HTML` file, they are designed to be accessed through a `web-server`.

Lets say you finally are able to fix all the directory paths and links, so what? This "fixed" code is surely not gonna be able to run on a server anyways.
So **Before** trying to "fix" something, I'll recommend that you first try accessing this site through a WAMP/LAMP stack on local environment.

Its pretty simple, If you are on linux then you can look up "installing LAMP". If you are on windows(*which seems to be the case*), then I'd suggest this portable [uWamp](http://www.uwamp.com/en/) stack. You don't even need to install it or care about the servers like apache/mysql.

Just Unzip the archive to a directory, and copy your code to the `www` folder at the root. All you need to do is run the `UwAmp.exe` located in the root, and once the sign turns green, you can access the code through this link. http://localhost/

Comment: not necessary, it was a typo in the path to link bootstrap.css

Comment: ok, cool!! I just wanted to address the root cause :) If you wish to continue the development without a local server, fine.

Comment: the root cause was a typo in my code, not the fact that I wasn't using a web server to view my website...

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, I was mistaken, I was more focusing on the development standards, and somehow missed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are giving the path correct (always for any file).
In your case there is and extra `>` at the end of the bootstrap css file path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css>" />
```

Change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```